# execute controller/action from javascript in rails3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a following function in my _new.html.erb. I would like to call a controller when the element_id_placeholder is changed:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    // When DOM loads, init the page.
    $(function() {
      // Executes a callback detecting changes with a frequency of 1 second
      $("#id_element_placeholder").observe_field(1, function( ) {                                       
        alert('Change observed! new value: ' + this.value );
        // call controller 

      });
    });

  </script>
```

I'm using rails 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use jQuery's ajax method:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "/articles/" + $(this).attr('value'),
success: function(data){}
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks that works but it goes to my controller/view. How would I call some method which would return me back the model Object or even a json object that I can build as part of that method?