# Ruby/Rails/AJAX/JQuery - On link click, passing a parameter and performing a controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to use clicking a link to perform and action in my controller called 'yes' but do so client side rather than having to refresh everytime a user clicks.

Before I had an link_to that routed to a action called "yes" and passed the id of a model I have called 'event'

```
      <%= link_to "yes", yes_path(event)%>   (in view)

      match 'user/:id/yes' => 'user#yes', :as => "yes"   {in routes.rb)
```

The problem issue is that every time the user clicks the link the page refreshes while it performs the yes action, so it will flow alot smoother if I can tell the backend to perform the actions client side.

S0  I found a reference here :   [execute controller/action from javascript in rails3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754571/execute-controller-action-from-javascript-in-rails3)

and took a look at the documentation :  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

And came up with this.  Where if the post is successful at the previous route from above change a css class for the link (change color).

```
 $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/user/" + $(this).attr('event') + "/yes/",
       success: function(){
           $(".like").click(function() {
           if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
           $(this).addClass("selected");
           return false;  } 
    });
```

I also added this is the bottom of the controller that the desired javascript is being used.

```
respond_to do |format|
     format.html { }
     format.js
end
```

So now my link_to looks like this

```
 <%= link_to "yes", yes_path(event), :class => "like", :remote => true %>
```

But the page is still refreshing and It doesnt look like its calling the AJAX at all.

- am I passing the parameter "event" properly as a jquery attribute?
- am I calling the link_to properly?
  This is my first time so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, possibly a few things?

I'd really appreciate any help

Comment: Did you make sure that the jQuery JS files are included in the head?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
$(".like").click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    var $self = $(this);
    $.post($self.attr("href"), function(response) {
        $self.addClass("selected");
    });
});
```

The first line binds the JavaScript to all elements with a class of `like`. `preventDefault` is the preferred way to prevent the default behavior of an anchor tag (navigate to the href). `$.post()` is shorthand for `$.ajax({ type: "POST" })`.

Whatever you want to happen after a successful post to the server goes that finally function call. The first argument is the response from the server.

Rich

Comment: @ChrisWesAllen `$.post` is one of a few shorthand methods for `$.ajax`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help.   2 questions => does the self.attr("href") servce as the url tag?  and where do I specify the route? should I the link_to tag?

Comment: @ChrisWesAllen The answer to both questions is that your ruby should work as is. The `link_to` route is translated into a URL that is placed in the `href` attribute of the resulting anchor tag. The JS above simply extracts the `href` and sends an Ajax POST to the URL instead of a standard GET request.